# How to have n variables in C#

Tags: c#, .net-4.0

imagine this code

```
for (int iDay = 1; iDay <= total_days; iDay++)
{

    question = CheckString(s.challenge_1_q);
    answer = CheckStringA(s.challenge_1_a);

    // more here
}
```

but what I really have is from `challenge_1_q` to `challenge_24_q` and `challenge_1_a` to `challenge_24_a`

what is my best option to have dynamic variables as today it's 24, "tomorrow" could be only 18.

is the use of `dynamic` the proper way? or I really need to have a `switch` and forget about dynamism ?

Comment: Isn't that what arrays/lists are made for?  Or I'm completely lost here.

Comment: @BeemerGuy this variables are from a `row` in a table and I really wanted to avoid doing more code like creating new class to handle this, I was just looking for an easy solution :)

Comment: if _tomorrow_ is only 18, what about next week when it's 115? =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a class called QuestionAnswer, then store a List on s.
The accessing code will look like this:

```
question = CheckString(s.QuestionAnswers[i].Question);
answer = CheckStringA(s.QuestionAnswers[i].Answer);
```

The QuestionAnswer class:

```
public class QuestionAnswer
{
  public string Question{get; set;}
  public string Answer{get; set;}
}
```

And the definition on your existing class:

```
public List<QuestionAnswer> QuestionAnswers = new List<QuestionAnswer>();
```

Instead of having dozens of variables, you add dozens of items to the list:

```
QuestionAnswer qa = new QuestionAnswer();
qa.Question = "What letter comes after A?";
qa.Answer = "B";
QuestionAnswers.Add(qa);
//repeat for all your questions.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also create `Structure`

```
struct QuestionBank
{
   public string Question;
   public string Answer;            
}
```

And use Something like this

```
 QuestionBank []Quiz = new QuestionBank[n]; //n is number of question and answers
 Quiz[0].Question = "SomeQuestion";
 Quiz[0].Answer = "SomeAnswer";

 Quiz[1].Question = "SomeAnotherQuestion";
 Quiz[1].Answer = "AnswerAsWell";

 .....

 Quiz[n].Question = "nth Question";
 Quiz[n].Answer = "nth AnswerAsWell";
```